# Is there still a difference between Math and StrictMath after Java 17 and JEP 306?

Tags: java, floating-point, java-17, strictfp

[JEP 306](https://openjdk.org/jeps/306), implemented in Java 17, provides always-strict floating point semantics, deprecating the `strictfp` flag.  Does this mean that `java.lang.Math` can be counted on to behave exactly the same as the analogous methods in `StrictMath` (i.e., that `java.lang.Math` methods can no longer be replaced by the JVM with intrinsics as used to be allowed)?  Does it also mean that there should no longer be any differences in floating point math results among different architectures, no matter which library is used?

I'm curious if I'm misunderstanding the new Java 17 feature, since we do see differences in today's code between Apple Silicon vs Intel.

Comment: What are your examples?

Comment: +1, I appreciate that @DuncG, but will not be able to answer right away.  I'll need to dig some to find sub-calculations where differences are coming up in a complex application.  I'd even need to bring in another team member because I only have access to intel at the moment.  We do see consistent differences in end results, though.

Comment: Being strict and using intrinsics (i.e. dedicated FPU instructions) is not a contradiction. It’s all about not using the old x87 FPU but SSE2 which has been introduced 2 decades ago. In case of `java.lang.Math` and the reference implementation, this is the case [since Java 15](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7175279). This applies to the HotSpot JVM and all implementations building on it or following suit. But as long as [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html) says that differences are allowed, you have to be prepared for them…

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `strictfp` is not a flag, this is a Java keyword ensuring the same calculation results on every platform while doing operations over floating-point variables (`float` and `double`).

As of your question, there are two major PRs in OpenJDK involving the changes for JEP 306

- [8244146: javac changes for JEP 306](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/3831)
- [8266530: HotSpot changes for JEP 306](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/3891)

If you look into the first one, especially into [StrictMath](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/3831/files#diff-a854e2217535f706e7a7cb2f4ecd3b52c4244d6ddac32ea67b40d65d9e2a0658L210-L231) you'll see that it now delegates directly to `j.l.Math` and the comment about `strictfp` semantics is now removed (along with `strictfp` keyword in OpenJDK codebase).
Moreover, starting from Java 17 `javac` issues an explicit warning for `strictfp` keyword (see `compiler.properties`:

> as of release 17, **all floating-point expressions are evaluated strictly** and `strictfp` is not required

So for the question

> Does this mean that java.lang.Math can be counted on to behave exactly the same as the analogous methods in StrictMath

The answer is "yes", for some methods e.g. `Math.sinh(double)` delegate to `StrictMath.sinh(double)` (and later on to `FdLibm.Sinh.compute(dobule)`) and e.g. method `StrictMath.toRadians(double)` delegates to `Math.toRadians(double)`. Eventually for floating-point variables it does not matter whether you call a method of `Math` or `StrictMath`, the same code is executed under the hood.

As of this part of the same question:

> i.e., that java.lang.Math methods can no longer be replaced by the JVM with intrinsics as used to be allowed

The PRs does not impose any changes regarding intrinsics which are platform-specific and applied by JVM at runtime regardless of whether operation is strict or not. Moreover, as [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) pointed out, there is no contradiction between strictness and intrinsics.

> Does it also mean that there should no longer be any differences in floating point math results among different architectures, no matter which library is used?

The answer is "yes as of Java 17 or newer". Prior to it there could be difference in results, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22335100/12473843. Before Java 17 if an operation over floating-point variable was not strict the standard assumed that

> a calculation might produce "the correct answer" in situations where exclusive use of the float value set or double value set might result in overflow or underflow.
> But as soon as for now the semantics is always strict you get the same result on all platforms.

See also [8268224: Cleanup references to "strictfp" in core lib comments](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/4348)

P.S.

> we do see differences in today's code between Apple Silicon vs Intel

I think it's quite natural for compiler to produce different code for different platforms, the question here is whether you see different results of computations on mentioned platforms.

Comment: Thanks!  Replying to the very last line, we **are** getting different results in low-order bits of calculation results, not just different code generation.  One hypothesis we've come up with is that a library in use may be in a jar that was compiled pre-java17, but we haven't been able to figure out if that's what's happening.  Small expressions we've tried have all given same results across architectures, so we don't have a reproducible case (MCVE) outside of cases going end-to-end in our application.

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg one more question: are the calculation results are NaNs or some 'real' values?

Comment: real values, no NaN's involved.