# In Java is StrictMath still preferred to Math for consistency?

Tags: java

I know that `StrictMath` follows given algorithms and will give the same result on every machine; however `Math` is more accurate and I see it being used more. Which is preferred? I would like reproducibility obviously, but also accuracy matters a great deal to me as well.

Comment: Why do you think `Math` is more accurate? It’s rather likely to be *faster* due to the lesser compatibility constraints.

Comment: The API says "This relaxation [of `Math` as opposed to `StrictMath`] permits better-performing implementations where strict reproducibility is not required." I presumed better-performing meant more accurate but I might have misinterpreted better-performing where it actually meant faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on true definition of [accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision), `StrictMath` is more accurate. Generally speaking `Math` is faster than `StrictMath`, but not always the case; often, the `Math` library functions simply calls a `StrictMath` implementation.

In any event, I think the answer to your question can be found straight from the [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) Javadoc:

> Unlike some of the numeric methods of class StrictMath, all implementations of the equivalent functions of class Math are not
>   defined to return the bit-for-bit same results. **This relaxation
>   permits better-performing implementations where strict reproducibility
>   is not required**.
>
> By default many of the Math methods simply call the equivalent method in StrictMath for their implementation. Code generators are
>   encouraged to use platform-specific native libraries or microprocessor
>   instructions, where available, to **provide higher-performance
>   implementations of Math methods**. Such higher-performance
>   implementations still must conform to the specification for Math.

For most applications, the general `Math` library is the better choice. If very small roundoff errors are a concern, then `StrictMath` is necessary. So don't get wrapped around the axle about inconsistency unless your *accuracy* must be very strong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have answer to your own question. You just have to choose based on your requirements.
I disagree that Math is generally faster than StrictMath. In some case yes, in some case not (depending on the operation). For this reason (as performance can't be the criteria) I would prefer StrictMath, as its results are reproductible..

For speed consider [FastMath](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/jacoco/org.apache.commons.math3.util/FastMath.java.html) Maybe Java + JNI and C++. Was faster some time ago, not sure if still the case today as the JVM are now extremely optimized.

**Note**

The library performance depends also on the JDK
See also [What's the difference between java.lang.Math and java.lang.StrictMath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232231/whats-the-difference-between-java-lang-math-and-java-lang-strictmath)